# How can I create an excel file with multiple sheets that stores content of a text file using python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, file, xlsxwriter

I need to create an excel file and each sheet contains the contents of a text file in my directory, for example if I've two text file then I'll have two sheets and each sheet contains the content of the text file.
I've managed to create the excel file but I could only fill it with the contents of the last text file in my directory, howevr, I need to read all my text files and save them into excel.

This is my code so far:

```
import os
import glob
import xlsxwriter


file_name='WriteExcel.xlsx'
path = 'C:/Users/khouloud.ayari/Desktop/khouloud/python/Readfiles'

txtCounter = len(glob.glob1(path,"*.txt"))


for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    content = f.read()
    print (len(content))

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_name) 
    ws = workbook.add_worksheet("sheet" + str(i))
    ws.set_column(0, 1, 30)
    ws.set_column(1, 2, 25)

    parametres = ( 
        ['file', content],
    ) 
    # Start from the first cell. Rows and 
    # columns are zero indexed. 
    row = 0
    col = 0

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row. 
    for name, parametres in (parametres): 
        ws.write(row, col, name) 
        ws.write(row, col + 1, parametres) 
        row += 1

    workbook.close()
```

example:
if I have two text file, the content of the first file is 'hello', the content of the second text file is 'world', in this case I need to create two worksheets, first worksheet needs to store 'hello' and the second worksheet needs to store 'world'.
but my two worksheets contain 'world'.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `pandas`. It in turn uses `xlsxwriter` to write data (whole tables) to excel files but makes it much easier - with literally couple lines of code.

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['Hello']})
sn_1 = 'hello'

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['World']})
sn_2 = 'world'

filename_excel = '1.xlsx'

with pd.ExcelWriter(filename_excel) as writer:
    for df, sheet_name in zip([df_1, df_2], [sn_1, sn_2]):
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know the length nor the content of my text files, as a matter of fact, in my project I need to extract data from excel files( not text files) and store them in another excel file

Comment: @A.khou Pandas is all about processing tables like excel or sql. So you can use it to both read and write excel files. It's much more appropriate and convinient tool than plain reading/writing data line by line (cell by cell). Of course, you may combine different approaches. If you manage to organize data in a tabular form then you can easily turn it into pandas dataframe and read/process/write much more efficiently and faster.

Comment: @ Poolka, pandas seems to be an intresting choice but I counld manage to transfrom `df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['Hello']})
sn_1 = 'hello'` inside a for loop, such as : `for i in range(0, txtCounter):` `df[i] = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['Hello']})
sn[i] = 'hello'`   the number of df and sn needs to be equal to number of text files in my directory